# Could not access the .json file of my cocoa framework in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I added a .json file to my cocoa framework and imported this framework to my iOS app but could not access the .json file.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: “filename”, withExtension: "json")
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!, options: .alwaysMapped)
            do {
                let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
} catch {
            }
        }
        catch {
        }
```

Here url is nil.

When I drag that .json file into my iOS app directory, it works well. So there is no issue with a .json format of the file.

Comment: You are accessing the wrong `Bundle`. Try accessing the bundle from the framework itself instead.

Comment: The above code written in one of the class in framework. Not in iOS app classes.

Comment: make sure that the file is included correctly in the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access it from the bundle of the framework not from the app main bundle

```
let bun = Bundle(identifier: <#frameworkBundleID#>)!
let url = bun.url(forResource: “filename”, withExtension: "json")
```